# AWS Amplify Auth sign-in issues with React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am experiencing an issue with the AWS Amplify Auth sign in button in React Native **only** (both in iOS and Android). I've tried both the `withAuthenticator()` implementation as well as a custom flow using `Auth.signIn()`. Clicking the sign in button does **absolutely nothing** with no error reported in the React Native debugger. The exact same configuration / user pool is used on a parallel web app and that **works absolutely fine** (tried using a different `userPoolWebClientId` just in case that was the issue). I have installed `amazon-cognito-identity-js` and `react-native link` and have reset all caches. The sign in ui renders fine, but the click action just does nothing.

import/config used:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from './aws-exports';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
```

and tried manual config as well:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  }
});
```

Using withAuthenticator:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, true);
```

relevant packages used:

```
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.0.12",
"aws-amplify": "^1.1.28",
"aws-amplify-react": "^2.3.8",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.12",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-apollo": "^2.5.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.59.9",
```

Oddly enough, the Forget Password action will send out a verification email, but the ui does not respond to the button click as well.

I'm guessing this is something very minor with configuration, but unable to determine what this issue is. It is also very odd that there is not any errors reported. Any insight is appreciated.

---

Below is complete output from the debugger - with the last line added after the click of the sign in button:

[image: React Native Debugger output]

Comment: Can you try set log level to DEBUG such that more info is shown?

Comment: @YikSanChan thanks for that idea - I've added the output above

Comment: I don't think that uncovered anything unfortunately - also tried setting the level to VERBOSE just in case, but no additional lines were added to the output.

Comment: @joknawe We encountered the same problem, how did you fix it or what was the root cause? Thanks!